# Place a marker by Latitude and Longitude

Tags: google-maps-api-3, location, gwt2

I have this code that suppose to place the marker by the latlng

```
public void initialize() {  
    geocoder = Geocoder.create();
    myOptions = MapOptions.create();        
    myOptions.setZoom(18);
    myOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.HYBRID);
    myOptions.setMapMaker(true);
    map = GoogleMap.create(
        Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);      

    GeocoderRequest request = GeocoderRequest.create();                 
    request.setLocation(LatLng.create(lat,lng));

    geocoder.geocode(request, new Callback() {
        public void handle(JsArray<GeocoderResult> rslts, GeocoderStatus status)
        {
            if (status == GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                location = rslts.get(0);
                map.setCenter(location.getGeometry().getLocation());
                marker = Marker.create();
                marker.setMap(map);
                marker.setPosition(location.getGeometry().getLocation());
            } 
        }
    });
```

When I tested with those coordinates (`45.48592686713835`, `-73.49009937672122`)
I only get the nearest address which is the icon A. But what I really wanted is the exact location showed with the green arrow.

[image]

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always get the nearest address, if one may be determined, when using the `Geocoder` to do a reverse geocode (convert LatLng to address). If you want to use the original coordinates, just place the `Marker` using the original coordinates. If you are going to convert the LatLng to an address or the closest that the Google `Geocoder` can get to an address, the results will always give you the LatLng of the nearest known `street_address`, `route`, `airport`, `transit_station`, `neighborhood`, `sublocality`, `locality`, etc.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but now I have this weird exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284367/weird-exception-when-placing-a-marker-with-latlng